# rails email validation with name and email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to write a validation for email filed .But some different way.
I will allow user to enter email in two format like **"name 'email@example.com' "**    and simple **'email@example.com'** .so basically i want to write a validation which will check that is valid email format in present in the value or not.

Just need a custom validation for check the valid email format is present in the input email value.

My model look like :

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :email ,presence: true
    validate :email_format

   def email_format
    ??? what to write here ???
   end

end
```

How can i write a validation for this.

Comment: Do you mean you need to validate a string that might look like "John Smith john@example.com" ?

Comment: yes i want  a validation which will check 'John<john@example.com>'as well and return ture .because its also a right format we are allowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to slightly modify the regular expression in your case.

```
validates :email, format: { with: /(\A([a-z]*\s*)*\<*([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\>*\Z)/i }
```

This will match the following formats.

```
soundar.rathinsamy@gmail.com
Soundar<soundar.rathinsamy@gmail.com>
Soundar <soundar.rathinsamy@gmail.com>
soundar<soundar.rathinsamy@gmail.com>
Soundar Rathinsamy<soundar.rathinsamy@gmail.com>
Soundar Rathinsamy <soundar.rathinsamy@gmail.com>
soundar rathinsamy <soundar.rathinsamy@gmail.com>
```

If you need some change continue editing this regular expression at [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/lEiJOwDz35)

Answer (score 1):

`validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i }`

Taken from apidock.com: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates

Answer (score 1):

This code extracts from the email a string between "<" and ">" but if it doesn't find a match then it takes the last word in the email... in either case it then takes that string and tests for a valid email.

So it should work for `"John john@example.com"` and `"John<john@example.com>"`

```
def email_format
  test_string = $1 if email =~ /\<([^\>]+)\>/
  test_string = email.split(' ').last unless test_string
  return if test_string =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
  errors.add(:email, "not a valid email")
end
```